# Force Replicate a Single Active Directory Object Programatically

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Does anyone know how to Force Replicate a Single Active Directory Object Programatically?

To be clearer I want to replicate this

```
CN=Sample User,OU=Sample OU,DC=company,DC=com
```

and the whole partition like this

```
DC=company,DC=com
```

I tried `DomainController.SyncReplicaFromAllServers Method` but I guess its used for partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres no way to do this on an object level, the best workaround is when you save your object try to save it on all domain contollers (if needed)

i.e. you have Domain Controller 1, Domain Controller 2, Domain Controller 3 do save in all rather than wait for it to replicate across.

Comment: oops!! this will introduce conflict in ObjectGUID and these entries will never sync. For every object there will be an objectGUID generated during creation time. Even the dn changes the guid wont change. Which means all your DCs are going to have different guid for the same entry and when they try to sync the guid will be conflicting. Mostly the ldap server drop this particular entry from syncing. So the next time when you do update "ldapmodify -h domain.com ... " which ever server it hits only that server will be updated. When you do ldapsearch you will get unexpected results

Comment: @kalyan - Dont you think AD will be smart enough to resolve the replication based on the last updated time stamp?

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer is no, you can not say to the ldap server to replicate only one object. The replication always works for partition/naming context.

Active Directory has a Global Catalog, that can be used. There are bunch of attribute marked as PAS attribute (Partial Attribute Set). From every Domain Controller the PAS attribute from every object will be synced immediately to all GC server by KCC. You can read more about this in [microsft document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978012.aspx) You can do the ldap searches on the GC port (3268) to find the object attributes quickly.

But if you can tell more specific details of your need that will help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But is there a way when I save an object let's say a User I have the option to save it in all domain controllers.  Because if have 6 domain controllers I have to wait for some time for it to be replicated on all.

Comment: I know there is an option in eDirectory. Using ndstrace I can trigger the sync immediately (which also can be run in command shell for keeping it in script). But i dont know about the AD

Comment: @Raymund: You could run all your creation operations for the Users and then only start a Replication sync for the partition they are in.

Answer (score 2):

You can replicate a single object by using "repadmin /replsingleobj" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742123.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I write this Code for i can make Rep between Two DC 
but its work only with Admin Permisson from IIS Pool 
in VS2015 rus as admin
in IIS you must change Application Pool Identity :

```
public static SecureString sSPasswordFianl;
public static void Securepass()
{
    string sPassword = "yourpassword";
    SecureString sSPassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char X in sPassword)
        sSPassword.AppendChar(X);

    sSPasswordFianl = sSPassword;
}

public static string RepTXADp01()
{
    try
    {
        Process Replactions = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procInfo.FileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Rep.bat");
        procInfo.WorkingDirectory = @""; //The working DIR.
        Securepass();
        procInfo.Verb = "runasuser";
        procInfo.Domain = "yourDomian.de";
        procInfo.UserName = "Username";
        procInfo.Password = sSPasswordFianl;
        procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process.Start(procInfo);  //Start that process.
         string output;
        return (output="OK");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return (ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

---

Reb.bat:

```
repadmin /replicate server1 Server2 DC=yourdomian ,DC=com
```